# Is a torn DV tape recoverable in any way?

Tags: firewire, tape, mini-dv

I am digitizing several DV tapes via a Sony handycam, a firewire cable, and a MacBook. 
Unfortunately, the tape of one of the DV tapes is torn: it only attaches to one of the spools, the other end is unattached and hangs out of the top.

Is there anything I can do to repair this tape such that I can digitize it? The tape is a JVC miniDV 60 (60/90ME).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mini DV tapes can be [spliced](http://www.dvdyourmemories.com/blog/minidv-tape-repair-guide-repair-minidv-tape/), so it should be easy enough to reattach it to the reel in similar way. Be sure to use [tape splicing tape](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NNSO11K) and not any other kind of tape. Be sure to only put splicing tape on the substrate of the video tape. Don't let the tape fold over onto the oxide side. If you end up splicing in the middle of the tape, you will see the picture pixelate and freeze around the splice.

I would recommend running the repaired tape through your player last just in case something isn't quite right with your splice and you accidentally damage the head.

Comment: Thanks, this worked out nicely. Small note: while I understand that splicing tape is the recommended method I have successfully used regular office tape. I did have to skip the spliced location manually though by taking out the tape, turning it past the splice and then putting it back in.